# Delphi - Passing large sets of data between routines

Tags: delphi, variables

Delphi XE6 - looking to write 3 or 4 RELATED applications, all of which will be using the same basic data routines, so I am looking to make a common, flexible API which all the apps will use.  My issue comes about with one portion of the API, moving COMPANY data.  Data on a company will have around 30 attributes, MOST of which will come from a table, but a handful will be calculations, etc...  I can put this in a simple class.

My question comes from the fact that I will not always know HOW MANY companies will get passed between routines. For example, I will have an API call that says "Look for Company name starting with some value.  There might be 1 or there might be 15.  How do I process the data in the subroutine but then provide access to it in the calling routine.  My first thought is to use a VAR TObjectList. The called routine will then CLEAR the TObjectList, process the data, and ADD to the TObjectList. I have not worked with TObjectList before.  Is there a reason NOT to do this?

Comment: If I don't know how many elements will be processed I think for the databases (especially if there will be multiuser environment)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a callback routine: a routine (A) that you pass as parameter to the companies extracting routine (B). B calls A for each matching record found in the dataset.

```
{MainForm}

procedure TMainForm.HandleCompany(ACompany: TCompany);
begin
  //For example
  Memo1.Lines.Add(ACompany.Name);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(ACompany.Address);
end;

procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyAPI.GetCompanies(HandleCompany);
end;

{MyAPI}

type
  TCompanyHandler = procedure (ACompany: TCompany) {of object};

procedure GetCompanies(CompanyHandler: TCompanyHandler);
var
  Company: TCompany;
begin
  for Company in Companies do
    CompanyHandler(Company);
end;
```